# Is there any method by which an excel file can be compared with some array in matlab without bringing excel files to matlab workspace.?

Tags: excel, matlab, import

I have large no of datas in excel file.Now i want to compare these datas in matlab but importing these excel files in matlab and then comparing it is very time consuming.Is there any method by which comparison can be done without bringing excel files to matlab workspace.?

Comment: You know you can import pieces of data from excel file by specifying the range. Read more into `xlsread` for that. On comparing data without importing, I don't think there's any way to perform that operation.

Comment: Why are you not comparing them in Excel? It offers also tons of function, what do you want to "compare" what couldn't be done in excel?